# Line thickness problem with CSS Speech bubble created with CSS

Tags: html, css

Using this the samples located [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/) I've put this together:

The code is located on [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/MissAmberClark/5uTQF/3/). If everything works when you run the sample, you should see a button with a question mark and clicking on that button the and the bubble should pop out.

The two things I can't seem to figure out right now is getting a 1px border on the triangle and vertically centering the triangle on the left edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the line thickness of the triangle, change the `top`, `left` and `border-width` values for the inner triangle so it's just 1px smaller than the larger triangle.

```
.triangle-border.left:after {
    top: 11px;
    left: -29px;
    border-width: 14px 29px 14px 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work. The triangle is now solid. [http://jsfiddle.net/MissAmberClark/5uTQF/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/MissAmberClark/5uTQF/10/)

Comment: @amber You don't need to comment anything out, just add this CSS to the end, or change only the values I've changed for .trangle-border.left:after (top, left, border-width). It still needs the bottom:auto, etc. to work. I've updated my answer to make my intentions clearer. See: http://jsfiddle.net/F7wzY/ for adding it at the end, or http://jsfiddle.net/sDxaA/ to see the values replaced.

Comment: Ah, okay. I eventually replicated what you did. Thank you!